# passing string to a function

Tags: c++, eclipse, string

I'm trying to pass a string to a function, which works fine when I use in Visual studio but I need run my code in linux with eclipse CDT as my IDE. The reason for choosing eclipse is I need to access matlab's engine.h in linux enviornment which is possible through eclipse.

I'm calling a function `MputVar2d(x, "x");` where `x` is a `vector <vector<double> >` and `"x"` is a string. and my function which is written in different header file is:

```
template <typename T>
void MputVar2d(const vector <vector<T> > &var, string name){
    extern Engine *ep;
    int row = var.size(), col = var[0].size();
    mxArray *matlab = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(row, col, mxREAL);
    T *pa = mxGetPr(matlab);
    for (int j = 0; j < var[0].size(); j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++){
            pa[i * row + j] = var[i][j];
        }
    }
    engPutVariable(ep, name.c_str(), matlab);
}
```

I get the following error when I'm running my code:

```
Invalid arguments:
Candidates are:
void MputVar2d(const std::vector<std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>>,std::allocator<std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>>>> &, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)
```

I tried executing my function as `MputVar2d(x, string("x"));`, or defining string as `std::string&` but it still gives the error.

Comment: The error message is inconsistent with the code presented as I'm writing this comment. Please post the real code.

Comment: does wrapping the value in a ``string`` fix it? I.E. ``MputVar2d(x, string("x"))``?

Comment: @Alf: should I paste an entire code? Its quite big, I though I pasted the relevant code.

Comment: At the very least probably the code around where you actually call the function.

Comment: @aruisdante: No, `MputVar2d(x, string("x"))` did not work..

Comment: You get the same error with none of the code inside `MputVar2d`, just an empty body, right?  The goal isn't to paste the relevant code, but a similar shorter program that gives the same error.

Comment: @Pranav: reduce it to a small example that readers can compile. the problem right now is that your error message is not produced by compilation of the code you're showing. specifically, the candidate function shown by the error message has the string argument passed by reference.

Comment: I doubt this code can be compiled at reader's end as it requires connectivity with matlab with lots of settings with libraries etc. However I will edit my post just in a min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd argument is a non-const string reference, judging by error message. You should make it const string& unless you are changing the string in the function and want the caller to see the change.

If you need more details, I will elaborate later today. For quick fix just change the function to take const string& name and you'll be fine.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always pass objects by const reference unless you are going to change and return them :-)